# How to inject into React Component props?

Tags: reactjs

The only way I know to inject props into a component is through a parent component  like so

```
render() {
  return <Child ...this.someProps />
}
```

How do I inject more props to the `Child` component dynamically through a function like so

```
inject(someProps, Child)
```

Similar to how redux-react `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Child)` works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: adding props to an existing component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750387/react-adding-props-to-an-existing-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher-order Components is what you are looking for: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775

At the end of the day you'll be wrapping your component with a parent one (`connect` is in fact a component).

Answer (score 0):

Make the children into an array with `React.Children.toArray()` and use `React.cloneElement()` to inject new props through the second argument.

You can put that into a function to make the notation you are indicating.

```
React.Children.toArray(children)
    .map((child, index) =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
            ...child.props,
            className: `${child.props.className || ''} ${index > 1 ? 'element-margin-top' : ''}`
        })
    )
```

In the example I am adding class names to the children depending on the index.