# React: adding props to an existing component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to clone an existing element with additional props.

For reference:

```
this.mainContent = <Hello message="Hello world!" />
```

I attempted to do something like

```
React.createElement(this.mainContent, Object.assign({}, 
   this.mainContent.props, { anotherMessage: "nice to meet ya!" }));
```

but it's not working.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You need to clone the element and add the additional props using [`React.cloneElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) e.g:

```js
const ClonedElementWithMoreProps = React.cloneElement(
  this.mainContent, 
  { anotherMessage: "nice to meet ya!" }
);
// now render the new cloned element?
```

Answer (score 48):

If you don't want to use `React.cloneElement()`, you can use the following snippet:

```
function AddExtraProps(Component, extraProps) {
    return <Component.type {...Component.props} {...extraProps} />;
}
```

Comment: Do note that this **does not preserve refs**. react.cloneElement preserves refs. ["This means that if you get a child with a ref on it, you won’t accidentally steal it from your ancestor. You will get the same ref attached to your new element."](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#react.cloneelement)

Answer (score 16):

`React.createElement()` takes either a string or a React class type as its first parameter, so that won't work if you're trying to clone an element.

Of course, [there's `React.cloneElement()` instead](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement), which does a deep copy of another React element and can optionally provide new props.

```
var foo = React.cloneElement(this.mainContent, {anotherMessage: "nice to meet ya!"});
```

Should work.

Comment: It was posted one minute afterwards :)