# Creating styled-component with React.createElement

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, createelement

I would like to create a `styled-component` with a function, taking *element* as an argument, which I create with `React.createElement` call.

```
const StyledComponent = (element) => styled(element)`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    `;

const myComponent = (props) => {
    const element = React.createElement('div', null, `Hello World!`);
    return (
        StyledComponent(element)
    );
}
```

This results in following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: [object Object].
```

I am probably missing something, but am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1893976/felix) answer was *almost* right, but you still need to pass the **className** property in the inline component function in order to get the styles defined in your *styled component* applied.

I was able to find the right answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750387/react-adding-props-to-an-existing-component), I decided to use the *JSX-syntax*, If you need to pass *refs*, use **React.cloneElement** instead.

Complete example:

```
const StyleMyElement = (Element) => styled(({ className }) => <Element.type {...Element.props} className={className} />)`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    ...
`;

...

const element = () => React.createElement('div', null, `Hello World!`);
const StyledComponent = StyleMyElement(element);

return (
    <StyledComponent />
)
```

Comment: do you have an idea how you could take the template literal, make an object of types, and pass in that dynamically? 

I was hoping something like

`export const StyleMyText = (type: TextStyleKey, Element: React.ReactElement) => styled(({ className }) => <Element.type {...Element.props} className={className} />)(TextStyles[type]);` would work?

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a HOC of a rendered React node. The following line is a render call:

```
const element = React.createElement('div', null, `Hello World!`);

// this is the same as:
const element = <div >Hello World</div>
```

What you may want is to replace the `createElement` with an actual functional component:

```
const element = () => React.createElement('div', null, `Hello World!`);

// this is the same as:
const element = () => <div >Hello World</div>
```

Now you can create a styled component and render it. Full (relevant) code:

```
const element = () => React.createElement('div', null, `Hello World!`);
const SComponent = StyledComponent(element);

return React.createElement(SComponent);
```

Comment: hello @Felix, thanks for clarification, I was clearly missing the difference between *element* and *Component* Your last code example works fine, with one minor issue - the *class* - defined by the styled function call will not be applied to the *props* of the resulting component. With other words: what is rendered is actually not styled.

Comment: Still fighting the right syntax. I need to pass *className* to props, so the generated classnames from the styled components will apply

Answer (score 0):

As of `styled-components` v4 you can just use the [`as` prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop=) to do this easily.

From the docs:

> If you want to keep all the styling you've applied to a component but just switch out what's being ultimately rendered (be it a different HTML tag or a different custom component), you can use the "as" prop to do this at runtime.

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Component = styled.div`
  color: red;
`;

render(
  <Component
    as="button"
    onClick={() => alert('It works!')}
  >
    Hello World!
  </Component>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented it:

**The component:**

```
export default function StyledCustomComponent({tag, className, children}) {
const customTag = React.createElement(tag);

const StyledCustomElement = styled(customTag.type)`
"some css rules"
`
return (
    <StyledCustomElement {...className}>
        {children}
    </StyledCustomElement>
  )
}
```

**Then calling the component in another file:**

```
<StyledCustomElement tag='div'> Some content <StyledCustomElement/>
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score -1):

Let make things simple
`import styled from 'styled-component'//import library for making styled components`

If for intance would like to create a styled component based on a `<p></p>` you would do lile this:

const MyP=styled.p
`color:red;
font-size:10px;
font-weight:bold`
;

You can ads as much `css` defintion as you want.
Now to use it:

`const MyComponent=()=>{
<MyP>
Hello
</MyP>
}`

Here instead of 'MyP' you could use 'p'(not styled).

It will also work for the const MyComponent=React.creatElement(MyP,null,'Hello');
Hope it helped

Comment: Thanks, but actually in my component, responsible for rendering of the *element*, the *element* is coming from outside, and should not be defined in the component.